# Mongo multi $elemMatch in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I need help to find resovled my problem here, i need to use $elemMatch multi times in php and i need and statement on multi arrays, hope on help here.

my MongoDB json array can look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56c1770ad857b64e379af41c"),
    "UUID" : "75a29021-9cc2-4896-934b-471fc4c7c3da",
    "CNETID" : "S11589612",
    "Url" : "asus-stikadapter",
    "LastChanged" : "2016-02-04 11:18:13",
    "Manufacturer" : {
        "UUID" : "ca21b6aa-2ba1-11e5-a2ac-0050569068de",
        "Title" : "ASUS",
        "Url" : "asus",
        "SKU" : "0A200-00021100",
        "EAN" : null
    },
    "Store" : {
        "Title" : "ASUS stikadapter",
        "Description" : "",
        "Price" : "31900",
        "PriceDiscount" : "0",
        "AllowDisplay" : "1",
        "Activated" : "1",
        "LastSynced" : "1000-01-01 00:00:00"
    },
    "Category" : [ 
        "4afe0190-5391-4022-a6af-ceb0e6c2db87", 
        "347004bc-32e2-4988-868d-cb7a9242ab2d", 
        "bb2b92ea-75a7-4d41-99fc-0ba3239b811f", 
        "f6883831-2cc1-4e4a-987c-6eb78bcfacf1"
    ],
    "PhotoCDN" : [ 
        {
            "photoUUID" : "5fb98931-4626-11e5-a899-0050569068de",
            "isPrimary" : "1",
            "cdnPath" : "{path}"
        }
    ],
    "Specifications" : {
        "Small" : [ 
            {
                "Header" : "Produktbeskrivelse",
                "Body" : "ASUS stikadapter"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Type",
                "Body" : "Stikadapter"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Lokalisering",
                "Body" : "Storbritannien"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Farve",
                "Body" : "Sort"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Designet for",
                "Body" : "P/N: 0A001-00230000"
            }
        ],
        "Full" : [ 
            {
                "Header" : "Type",
                "Body" : "Stikadapter"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Farve",
                "Body" : "Sort"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Farvekategori",
                "Body" : "Sort"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Lokalisering",
                "Body" : "Storbritannien"
            }, 
            {
                "Header" : "Designet for",
                "Body" : "P/N: 0A001-00230000"
            }
        ],
        "Search" : [ 
            {
                "HeaderID" : "T0000010",
                "Body" : "Stikadapter"
            }, 
            {
                "HeaderID" : "T0000087",
                "Body" : "Sort"
            }, 
            {
                "HeaderID" : "T0005917",
                "Body" : "Sort"
            }, 
            {
                "HeaderID" : "T0000046",
                "Body" : "Storbritannien"
            }, 
            {
                "HeaderID" : "T0003807",
                "Body" : "P/N: 0A001-00230000"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What i want it search iside the `Specifications -> Full` on both HeaderID and Body.

My problem i can only use `$elemMatch` one time, i use find command in php and what i want to search after its like

**Find all products there match**

```
HeaderID = T0000087 and Body = Black, White or Yello AND
HeaderID = T0000087 and Body = UK, USA or DK
```

And my search filter look like this as i testing its not working right now!

```
$this->_searchFilter = [
    'Category' => $this->categoryUUID,
    'Store.AllowDisplay' => '1',
    'Store.Activated' => '1',
    'Specifications.Search' => [
        ['$elemMatch' => [
            'HeaderID' => 'T0000010',
            'Body' => 'USB-kabel'
        ]],
        ['$elemMatch' => [
            'HeaderID' => 'T0000087',
            'Body' => 'Brunsort'
        ]]
    ]
];
```

and my debug MongoDB look like this

```
db.getCollection('product').find({ "Specifications.Search": { $elemMatch: { 'HeaderID' : 'T0000010', 'Body' : "Stikadapter"}}})
```

Comment: Please define "not working" a bit more precisely... ;) As your debug query works with your data on my machine...

Comment: Its mean, its not return nothing, somthing about its not will allow the way i use it on, and i can find a way to use "and" and "or" commands inside.

Comment: As written: your debug query works perfectly on my machine: http://imgur.com/lElRawQ

Comment: Yes, and if you need a secound elemMatch how will you wirte the secound? thats my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the awsare, what i want is use $and and $or and multi $elemMatch and my code looks like this.

```
db.getCollection('product').find({
    $and: [{ 
        $or :[{
            "Specifications.Search": { 
                $elemMatch: { 
                    'HeaderID' : 'T0000010', 
                    'Body' : "Stik"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "Specifications.Search": { 
                $elemMatch: { 
                    'HeaderID' : 'T0000010', 
                    'Body' : "Stikadapter"
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
})
```